# Getting 400: Bad Request on delete request using asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, rest

I'm trying to delete a post using it's post ID
But every time I try to delete a post 400:bad request shows up in the console

```
var deletepost=function(deleteid){
    $.ajax({
        
        url:"http://localhost:12091/api/post/"+deleteid,
        method: "DELETE",
        header:"Content-Type:application/json",
        crossdomain: true,
        complete:function(xmlhttp, status){
            if(xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                alert("Post Deleted");
            }
            else{
                console.log(xmlhttp.status+":"+xmlhttp.statusText);
                console.log("unsuccessful");
            }
        }
        
    })
}
```

This is what I have in my controller:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        postRepository.Delete(id);
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Edit: I tested the functionality using Postman. Works fine

Comment: If you only pass an `id` to the controller, you could have used `GET` method instead

Comment: @LongLuong but I want to delete the post. Don't I need "DELETE" method for that?

Comment: so I guess you are calling your `Delete` in the controller wrong.
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29123945/4492997)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending the AJAX request using a `DELETE` HTTP verb, so you need to add the `[HttpDelete]` annotation to the action in your controller. You'll also need to add the `[FromUri]` annotation to the argument for the model binder to recognize and populate it. Try this:

```js
var deletepost = function(deleteid) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:12091/api/post/" + deleteid,
    method: "DELETE",
    header: "Content-Type:application/json",
    complete: function(xmlhttp, status) {
      if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert("Post Deleted");
      } else {
        console.log(xmlhttp.status + ": " + xmlhttp.statusText);
        console.log("unsuccessful");
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```csharp
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult Delete([FromUri]int id) 
{
  postRepository.Delete(id);
  return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Note the removal of the `crossdomain` property in the AJAX request. It has no relevance to this logic.